# Redshift STL_LOAD_ERRORS col_length (256) different than DDL (12000)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, varchar

I have a table called 'sales' which has a column called 'reason'. I am trying to load data into the column.

The data is;

> "They found an issue with the software causing one of the chips an
> issue leading to the oven not operating correctly to being with. They
> rewrote the software while on site, software downloaded into all
> controllers and checked. The oven was left working as per usual when
> the team left site
> "

The column in the table is created as below;

> reason, character varying(12000), null, ENCODE lzo

In stl_load_errors the error message is 'String length exceeds DDL length'

I have checked:

> OCTET_LENGTH(reason) = 296

I am confused to why Redshift thinks the column length is 256 when it is actually 12000.

This happens on an Merge data in Glue. BUT when I truncate the table it processes fine.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: How do you insert data in the table?

Comment: I am using Glue. 

Source: is Direct data connection from another redshift table.

Target: I have tried both Redshift access types.
(Direct data connection & Glue Data Catalog tables).

Handling of data and target table
MERGE data into target table - this doesn't work
TRUNCATE target table - this seems to work

Comment: FYI, on Redshift you can have a table of type `TEXT` that does not require a length. (It _might_ be limited to 65535 bytes, but you don't need to specify the size.)

Comment: I have tried that, but TEXT is replaced by varchar(256). I will just have to truncate the table for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same bug and only could solve editing the script after finding this post. Hope it helps until AWS fix it.

[Glue job failed when trying to perform a merge into Redshift table due to string length limits for VARCHAR/TEXT characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77382178/glue-job-failed-when-trying-to-perform-a-merge-into-redshift-table-due-to-string?rq=2)